Express $a(s)$ in terms of $F(z)=\int_0^{\infty}a(s)z^sds$?
Let's consider a function $$F:z\mapsto F(z)=\int_0^{\infty}a(s)z^sds,$$ where $z$ is a real number in some small interval, say $(0,z_0)$. Also, the coefficients $a(s)$ are nonnegative, and they enjoy nice growth conditions as $s\to\infty$.
My question is: for a given $s\geq0$, how can we express $a(s)$ in terms of $F(z)$?
This is an absolutely continuous version of the power series question that we have $b(k)=\frac{1}{k!}\partial_z^kG(0)$ when we consider the power series $G(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b(k)z^k$.

Note that
$$
z^s = e^{s \ln(z)}
$$
so
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty a(s) z^s , \mathrm{d}s
&= \int_0^\infty a(s) e^{s \ln z} , \mathrm{d}s\
&= \int_0^\infty a(s) e^{ -s(-\ln z)} , \mathrm{d}s\
&= \mathcal{L}{a(s)}(-\ln z)
\end{align*}
$$
where $\mathcal{L}$ denotes the unilateral Laplace transform.
